# Detect location change as it's happening rather than after - Blazor

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a reset function where I reset some `AppState` variables on every location change. The destination pages then set those values appropriately in their `OnInitializedAsync`. I detect the location change detection like so:

`NavigationManager.LocationChanged += async (s, e) => await LocationChanged(s, e);`

Problem is `LocationChanged` is being called AFTER `OnInitializedAsync` of the destination pages rendering the whole mechanism pointless. How can I detect location change earlier?

Comment: I'm assuming your event is in the "old" page.  When you register with 'LocationChanged' you join the queue.  What happens when is not in your control.  In general the Router is likely to be first in the queue, and therefore routes to the new page before you get a look in.  Any call to `OnInitialized{Async}` on a routed component is a location change.  May be a stupiud question, but with one line of code to go on, why not `reset` when `OnInitialized{Async}` is called on a routed component?

Comment: I should have been more clear. `Reset` is not on the old page but on the `MainLayout`, so on every page. I am trying to avoid having a reset on every `nInitialized{Async}` in the whole application.

Comment: I don't think you can do this universally in `MainLayout`.   There are several ways that I can think of.  The simplest is to create your own component that inherits from `ComponentBase` and implements the reset in `OnInitializedAsync`.  You then call `base.OninitializedAsync` first whenever you override it.  The slightly more complex is to re-write `RouteView` or `AuthorizeRouteView` so the reset takes place as part of the View Load.  I can show you how as an answer if your interested.

Answer (score 0):

With .NET 7 onwards Blazor has `NavigationManager.RegisterLocationChangingHandler()` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.components.navigationmanager.registerlocationchanginghandler?view=aspnetcore-8.0

The handler is triggered before the navigation change and can be used to prevent the change if desired.